# Lightning: Template reuse

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I'd like to create basic [template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_template_overview.htm) to inherit this template for all apps in my org:

```
<aura:component isTemplate="true" extends="aura:template">
    <aura:set attribute="title" value="Aura Notes"/>
    <div class="container">{!v.body}</div>    
</aura:component>
```

But title should be set outside template, as well as body. What is the right way to do this.

I am trying to do like this but it doesn't work. Custom component is not rendered inside `.container` element:

```
<aura:application template="c:template">
    <aura:set attribute="title" value="Aura Notes"/>
    <c:customCmp/>        
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates have very specific restrictions/limitations and are used to generate the initial application HTML document sever side - the only place in Lightning Components where server side HTML generation/rendering is used today. This is the "bootstrapping" part of the lifecycle and is meant primarily to allow you to customize the splash/background of your app before the framework has initialized.

Looking at your example I believe what you really want is a base application that you then extend instead of using a template.

Comment: Doug, are there any examples of how a template would customize the splash/background of an app?